# How do I wait for all observables to execute sequentially?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, rxjs

I understand that forkJoin will wait for all observables to fire, but I need those observables to fire in order. I might be misunderstanding the usage of concat, but our code looks like this more or less:

```
const observables: Observable<ArrayBuffer>[] = [];

  observables.push(
    Observable.fromPromise(this.file.readAsArrayBuffer(directoryPath, filePath))
      .map((arrayBuffer) => {
        // work done here on "object", name obsfucated for client reasons
        return arrayBuffer;
      },
    ),
  );
});

return Observable.concat(observables).map((arrayBuffers) => {
  //we return "object" from here that's also obfuscated for client reasons
});
```

Is this wrong? Will this not fire in order? We keep having issues with it.

Comment: In my usage of rx I have only been able to do this by keeping the observables separate and then in the `onNext` section `subscribe` to the next observable in the sequence .

Comment: what issue do you keep having?

Comment: you might want to read this article [Learn to combine RxJs sequences with super intuitive interactive diagrams](https://blog.angularindepth.com/learn-to-combine-rxjs-sequences-with-super-intuitive-interactive-diagrams-20fce8e6511)

Answer (score 1):

A promise is eager so will always directly start executing. You can defer this by wrapping it in `Observable.defer(() => myPromise())`.

If you first want to create an array of observables which you then want to have executed in order sequentially you can use `.concatMap()` or `.concatAll()`.

```
const myObsArray = [];
myObsArray.push(Observable.defer(() => Promise.resolve(1));
myObsArray.push(Observable.defer(() => Promise.resolve(2));

Observable.from(myObsArray).concatAll().subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```